# Why is Excel VBA changing the year of my date when I format it?

Tags: vba, excel, date, formatting

I'm trying to format a date variable to look like `"mmm-yy,"` but when the date is 2016, after the formatting takes place, the date changes to 2015. Here is my code:

(Result is the string result of an input box, the box requests that the user enter the date in `mmm-yy` form, and there is a test before this code to ensure that there is a hypen as the fourth character.

The other validation tests occur after this code, as I found that the string had to be formatted as a date in order for the tests to work.)

```
        result2 = result
        result2 = Format(result2, "mmm-yy")
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: With "sep-16" the 16 is assumed as day and the year is assumed as not given, so it is assumed as this year. So the date is September, 16th 2015.

Answer (score 0):

Have the user put the date in as the program understands (e.g. mm/dd/yyyy) if the value resulting from the input box is going to be set equal to the value of a variable with type date.

If, for some reason, the user must enter the date in "mmm-yy" format, set the input equal to the value of a string variable and then deconstruct the variable with [Month*] = Left([result],3) and [Year] = "20" & right([result],2). Then, you have to build the date so that it can be set to a new variable of type date to put into your Format function.

*Of course, you'll have to have some key to translate "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", etc. into values 01, 02, 03, etc.

The below tested correctly for me:

Public Sub UserDateEntry()

```
Dim strUserEntry As String
Dim intMonth As Integer, intYear As Integer

strUserEntry = InputBox("Enter month & year in ""mmm-yy"" format.", "Date Entry", "Sep-16")

intMonth = Month(DateValue("01 " & Left(strUserEntry, 3) & " 2012"))
intYear = 20 & Right(strUserEntry, 2)

Application.Range("DateLoc").Value = Format(intMonth & " 01 " & intYear, "mm/dd/yyyy")
```

End Sub

Comment: This suggestion carried the code further successfully, but did not place the correct date on my sheet. Here's the portion of my code where the date is placed in the sheet: dateloc.Value = result2  (dateloc is the range where the date is placed) when I hover over result2 after running this portion of the code, it says the correct date, but when it is placed in the sheet, the year changes (from 16 to 15). Suggestions?

Comment: I really don't know why you keep getting 2015 when 2016 was entered. You're setting the result of the user entry for the InputBox equal to a variable of type String, right? Can you post your code so it's clearer to understand?

Comment: finally got it to work - just broke down the elements of the date and concatenated in a string at the end of the code before placing in the sheet - DateFinal = Mnth & "/" & dd & "/" & Yr